# Slick Slider error after Filter

Tags: slick.js

Slick slider error when click nav after filter

Demo:[enter link description here](https://jsbin.com/sifiqabaya/1/edit?html)

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your javascript script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(4){
   ...
});
```

Remove the number 4:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   ...
});
```